# How to change text position of Progress dialog?

Tags: java, android

Right now if i use the "setMessage()" function it sets the message to the right of the progress bar, i need to set it on the bottom.

[Imgur](https://i.imgur.com/b0snYv7.png)

What is the simplest way to acheive this?

Comment: You can use a custom layout, however, using a Dialog for progress is not recommended, it provides bad user experience.

Comment: Just create a layout file with Progress Bar and TextView, include that layout where you want to show the progress and then change its visibility.